# Why I can't add a class library project reference to a Silverlight project?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, reference

I am a newcomer to Silverlight and while I have been following some tutorials I wanted to create a new project with a class library so that I can use it from my page's xaml.cs code behind.

But when I tried to add my class library project I get a warning message saying:

*You can only add project references to
other Silverlight projects in the solution*

It is clear what it says. But what is the reason behind this? Why I cannot add a class library project reference to a Silverlight project?

Thanks

Comment: Just to note: you can however link the other way (include Silverlight libraries in traditional .Net apps). This solves the problem of sometimes needing to share code between apps (usually business logic).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of regular Class Library, you can use the "Silverlight Class Library" template. The reason why you can't use a regular Class Library is that the Common Language Runtime of Silverlight is different than the CLR of "regular" .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to a class library to a silverlight application but that class library needs to be a **Silverlight Class Library**.

When you use Add Project ont he solution select the "Silverlight" option under "Visual C#" ( or "Visual Basic" or even "Visual F#").  You will see a template for a "Silverlight Class Library".  Your class library needs to have used this template in order to be eligable to be reference by a Silverlight application or other Silverlight Class libraries.